# Show number of objects in Many to Many Relationship? (Django)

Tags: python, django

I have a simple blog created in Django with Posts and Comments for each post. I'm trying to show the total number of comments for each post on the home page but I can't get the total to show.

Here's my model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    content_text = models.TextField(blank=False, max_length=3000)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    content_text = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

My views.py:

```
def home(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'post/home.html', {'posts': posts})
```

And lastly my html file:

```
{{ post.comments.count }}
```

The other information displays correctly such as `{{post.title}}`. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **`annotate(...)`** as

```
from django.db.models import Count


def home(request):
    posts = Post.objects.annotate(comments_count=Count('comment'))
    return render(request, 'post/home.html', {'posts': posts})
```

and in your template,

```
{{ post.comments_count }}
```

Comment: that worked! Thank you for the quick response. Will `Post.objects.annotate(comments_count=Count('comment'))` still grab the comments count as well as all the other Post objects? I'll have to read up more on annotate

Comment: Yes.. In short, `annotate(...)` is something like ***`AS`*** expression in SQL